# Java Update Sql statement error

Tags: java, sql, db2

I am trying to update a `Db2` database using `Java` and the following code:

```
String sSqlString = "UPDATE P6DEVCDB00.P6OSTAPF SET STATVAL = '" + sStatVal + "' WHERE  OPIID = '" + sOperationsitemid + "' AND CONGRPC = '" + sConfigGrpCode  + "'";

// Do your select on a Db table.
//statement = con.createStatement();
statement = con.prepareStatement(sSqlString);

int RowsAffected = statement.executeUpdate();
con.commit();
System.out.println(RowsAffected);
```

I then get the following error :

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-7008, SQLSTATE=55019, SQLERRMC=P6OSTAPF  ;
P6DEVCDB00;3, DRIVER=3.58.81
```

I have printed out the sql that it's going to run :

```
UPDATE  P6DEVCDB00.P6OSTAPF SET STATVAL = 'ON' 
WHERE   OPIID = 'B20120707000681531' AND CONGRPC = 'STKLSTSTAT
```

When I run this sql directly with a SQLUI tool it works and the record gets updated...

Comment: does the user you're connected with have the proper rights to do an update on that DB ?

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, yes the user has the proper rights

Comment: Are you sure that you connect to correct DB schema?

Comment: Yes Its the correct Schema When I run the same update statement directly it works..

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing... either your schema, your tablename or one of the field name is not valid, causer the code syntax seems perfectly legit...

Comment: @Renier : there must be something different when you try it from your code and you try it "directly" , was it the user you log in or an extra line at the top of your query...

Comment: @Bartdude Thanks for your reply.. The user I use is exactly the same in both cases, the only difference is Me trying to excecute the SQL update through Java( This fail's and gives the -7008 SQLCode error, what I mean by directly is by running the SQL in DB2 SQL Query tool(This works) the same Sql is used but from java it gives the error. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: What is the DB2 version and platform that you're connecting to? I'm assuming your Java program and your query tool connect to the same database.

Comment: Please note that you're potentially open to SQL Injection - you should be using prepared statements.  What's the actual text of the error message?  I have a feeling that it may be complaining if you don't have the table setup for journaling (database transactions) - That's reason code 3 (for iSeries, at least).

Comment: @mustaccio the OS = Version 6 Release 1, DB2 for i5/OS V5R3 the Jar files I am using to connect is : db2jcc.jar,db2jcc_License_cu.jar and db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar and yes I am connecting to the same Database.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thank you for the tip I will change to Prepared statements, I will have a look at journaling and see if that's not my problem. And will send the error text.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I have enabled journaling on the specified table i need to update and it works! Thank you but now this means that I need to enable it for all the tables... and I don't think its the right way? The reason why I ask is why will it work when i run thr SQL on a DB2 SQL Query tool? Could this be then something to do with the way I am connecting? Here is my connection code:

Comment: public Connection getDbConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException,
   SQLException {
  Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
  Connection connection = null;
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:db2://DatabaseSystem/CLBD", "User",
    "password");

  return connection;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're attempting to use transactions over tables that are not 'journaled' - that is, setup for transactions.

Ideally, you *should* set up all tables (that will be run under a transaction) as journaled, **specifically to test that property**; regardless of being able to simulate failures, you need to make sure that your code can handle being under transactions.
Also, depending on your situation, you may not need to explicitly manage transactions.  If you're using a framework like [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/), they can usually manage transactions *for* you, although this will usually mean that you still need journaling on your iSeries tables.

If you're just trying to test basic code behavior, look into using an in-memory database, such as [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) (can emulate some LUW DB2 behavior, but not library lists, unfortunately) - this will absolve you of the need to have a connection to your box, and to set up journaling.